# micro-segmentation for blockchain nodes using SPIFFE/SPIRE to avoid rogue nodes

Tags: security

As a blockchain microservices developer, I observed that most, if not all, public blockchain nodes do not authenticate or authorise with each other before communicating.

If one may apply principles of micro-segmentation to blockchain nodes using SPIFFE/SPIRE, following the principle of application/workload identity in cloud native, every node will need this identity that is verifiable with each peer, this can potentially further enhance the security of public blockchain?

Sort of an overlay network of identities on top of the network.